# Typescript for a reduce {keyName, keyValue} attributes function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to implement a typed function to convert :

```
[
  { key: "key1", value: "my string" },
  { key: "key2", value: 123 },
  // other { key , value }, the function needs to be generic
]
```

into

```
{ key1: "my string", key2: 123, ... }
```

The implementation is quite easy but I can't find a way to have a correct type with typescript. It should look like this

```
type Attribute<Key, Value> = { key: Key; value: Value };

const myAttributes = [
  { key: "key1", value: "my string" },
  { key: "key2", value: 123 },
];

const reduceAttributes = (attributes: Attribute[]) => { // <== Generic type 'Attribute' requires 2 type argument(s).
  return attributes.reduce((acc, attribute) => {
    acc[attribute.key] = attribute.value;
    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<string, any>) as ???; // <== should find a way to cast to expected type
};
```

But I'm looking for a way to have :

```
const x = reduceAttributers(myAttributes)
//    ^?
//    x : {key1: string, key2: number}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the entries types may be defined as

```
type Entries<T> = { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T]
type FromEntries<T extends [any, any][]> = {
    [K in T[number][0]]: Extract<T[number], [K, any]>[1]
}
function entries<T extends { [s: string]: unknown; }>(o: T) { return Object.entries(o) }
function fromEntries<T extends [any, any][]>(o: T) { return Object.fromEntries(o) }
```

you may define your type as

```
type Attribute = { key: "key1"; value: string } | { key: "key2"; value: number };

type AttributeRecord<T extends Attribute[] = Attribute[]> = {
    [K in T[number]['key']]: Extract<T[number], {key: K}>['value']
}
function fromAttrbutes<T extends Attributes[]>(attrs: T): AttributeRecord<T> {
  return Object.fromEntries(attrs.map(({key, value}) => [key, value])
  // or the same
  return attrs.reduce((o, {key, value}) => Object.assign(o, {[key]:value}), {})
  // or the same
  return attrs.reduce((o, {key, value}) => (o[key] = value, o), {})
}

type X = AttributeRecord;
//   ^?
// type X = { key1: string; key2: number;}
```

This will properly work for any subtype of Attribute[] (I may have forgot to add `readonly` to remove warnings for as-const types)

If you want to *just* make a non-generic type, use

```
type Y = Record<Attribute['key'], Attribute['value']>
//   ^?
// type Y = { key1: string | number; key2: string | number; }
```

Comment: Also consider if you actually need reduce or can use `Object.fromEntries`

Comment: Thank you @Dimava, your answer helped me, but the goal was in fact to be able to call reduceAttributes with a generic type. (ie, for any kind of "attribute list"). I'll update the question

Comment: @Drico does this wotk for yo now?